# show all border lines for a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

why does :

```
 <table style="border:1px solid black; " class="table-bordered table-striped table">
            <colgroup>
                <col id="Col1" />
                <col id="Col2" />
                <col id="Col3" />
                <col id="Col4" />
                <col id="Col5" />
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="border:1px solid black;" scope="col">@T("Code")</th>
                    <th style="border:1px solid black;" scope="col">@T("Product")</th>
                    <th style="border:1px solid black;" scope="col">@T("Unit Price")</th>
                    <th style="border:1px solid black;" scope="col">@T("Quantity")</th>
                    <th style="border:1px solid black;" scope="col">@T("Value")</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
```

look like:
[image]

I want to show all the borders of all the cells?
Should the style in the `<table>` have done this?

Comment: border="1" in your table..

Comment: PLease post generate HTML

Comment: possible show us the http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The question lacks the *crucial* information: the markup for the data rows and the style sheets being applied.

Comment: If you think that C#, ASP, or HTML5 (as opposite to HTML in general) is relevant to the problem, please explain how. If not, remove the misleading tags. And probably you should add the css tag.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela thanks for the 'close' suggestion....real team player....on a positive note - thanks for all the answers guys

Comment: @John you tag HTML5 and then accept an answer that is incorrect in HTML5... My comment on his answer links to docs on what `border` means in HTML5. Note that just because it may appear correctly in some browsers does not mean it is correct. [a fiddle of Patrick Hofman's answer](http://jsfiddle.net/9RDVr/1/) shows how to correctly do it with CSS, which is why it was upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `border="1"` in your table like this `<table border="1">`

[Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3paJn/) Using `border="1"`

[Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RDVr/) Using `style="border:1px solid black;"`

Comment: This is wrong. He should use CSS. [HTML 4.01 border attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#adef-border-TABLE) vs [HTML 5 border attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-table-element.html#attr-table-border)

Answer (score 4):

When using css you can set the border of a table and it's cells like this

```
table, th, td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Don't need to set **border:1px solid black;** in every table data. border="1" is enough. see my jsfiddle...

Comment: You are right. My bad. When using css you need to specify this, but you can use the border attribute on tables. Edited answer to show how to do this in css.

Comment: This is better, because it is the way to go for html5 and is compliant with earlier versions.

Comment: To make this look a little prettier you could take a look at the border-collapse css property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between Table border and css border. To apply border to each cell you have to use Table border using table property called `border` or apply css border to each cell of the Table. To learn more please visit following [LINK](http://www.html.am/html-codes/tables/table-border.cfm)

Comment: This answer got a down-vote.Could you please share your reason for downvote, whoever downvoted this.